# PyTorch Transformer seeing future tokens despite subsequent mask?

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I've been experimenting with PyTorch's Transformer and noticed something odd. I'm using the correct subsequent mask, but it seems like the decoder is still influenced by future tokens. Here's my code:

```
transformer_model = nn.Transformer(
    nhead=1, 
    d_model=4,
    num_encoder_layers=1,
    num_decoder_layers=1,
    batch_first=True,
    dropout=0.0, 
)
src = torch.rand((1, 10, 4))
tgt = torch.rand((1, 20, 4))

transformer_model.eval()

out = transformer_model(
    src, 
    tgt,
    tgt_mask=transformer_model.generate_square_subsequent_mask(tgt.size(1)),
)

out_limited = transformer_model(
    src, 
    tgt[:, :10, :],
    tgt_mask=transformer_model.generate_square_subsequent_mask(tgt[:, :10, :].size(1)),
)

print((out[:, :10]-out_limited).mean()) # should output 0, but it doesn’t
```

I'd expect the output for the first 10 positions in out to be identical to out_limited, but they're not. Is this a known issue? Any insights or workarounds?